# Identityserver4 2.0 on Azure gives 502.5 error

Tags: azure, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to run Identityserver 4 with .net core 2.0 on Azure.
My deployment is done on a brand-new app-service in a brand-new serviceplan using continuous deployment using bitbucket.

Deployment succeeds fine, but when opening the url, I see a 502.5 error.

I tried running the dotnet command using kudu, but that just stops right after starting without returning an error.

My solution does not contain a web.config, but is is generated as following. The only change is that I enabled stdOutLogging.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Solution.Identity.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Logfiles are created at the given location, unfortunately all files have a size of 0 bytes.

The event log gives the following data:

```
<Event>
    <System>
        <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module"/>
        <EventID>1000</EventID>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-11-26T11:49:13Z"/>
        <EventRecordID>149782328</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>XXXXXX</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/SOLUTIONIDENTITY' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\Solution.Identity.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : c0000374.</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

0x80004005 means a missing file or a version conflict, but which file can be missing when all files are retrieved by nuget on deploy-time (there are no libraries included in bitbucket repository). 
I can't get a clear description of what c0000374 means.

The project runs locally on kestrel and through IIS without errors.

The project file is as following

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-Solution.Identity-f67088a4-3844-4ec8-abd5-12b6488e53f3</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>

  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\solutionidentity - Web Deploy.pubxml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="identity.pfx">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My program.cs looks as following

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();
```

Things tried

- with and without aspNetCoreTargetApplicationManifest
- deploying for any cpu and x86 only
- deploying using VS2017, deploying using continuous deployment
- creating a new app service
- enabling stdout logging
- running the dotnet command as stated in web.config within kudu
- forcing the dotnet runtime to use version to 2.0.0 or 2.0.3 using fx-version command

I think I have tried almost everything I could find on Microsoft fora, stack overflow and google. I am somewhat out of options. I hope some of you guys can give me a clue.

Comment: Tried changing all PlatformTarget elements to AnyCPU?

Comment: For all libraries under my control I changed the target to x86, but no effect.

Comment: They should be AnyCPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the probleem using my bitbicket repository.
Having quite a straight forward setup I decided to replay all my commits one by one until something didn’t work anymore.

Identityserver likes a x509 certificate to sign the given out tokens. Unfortunately azure doesn’t allow just loading certificates (pfx) using a “new X509Certificate2(path,password)” call.
This is because the private key is then added to the local user store which is not present in azure.
The resolution is to either load the certificate using the dashboard, or specify the store as a third parameter while constructing the X509Certificate2 object.

The question does arise, why wasn’t this logged? And why does this crash the dotnet process, even when embedded in a try/catch block?

This issue was reported to azure support services as well, but I solved it before they did. I did ask them this as well, but as .net framework development is another department, I guess I won’t be informed about that anymore.

Everyone thanks for thinking along.